# iPhone Developer License issues

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

Ok so I had my iPhone replaced today.. And for some reason now my apps won't download onto my new phone. I backed up my phone and everything before I got this new phone. my phone pops up in the edit schemes thing in Xcode, but when i run it on my phone it says "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." When i look in the organizer, it shows my phone connected with a green light next to it. under the software version, it says "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version." Does that have anything to do with it? I don't know what to do, I've looked at everyone elses problem with the executable not being found but through their questions I could not solve my issue. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable the phone for development in the organizer?

Comment: I assume so @PascalBelloncle

Comment: did you update the OS on your phone?  Yes, XCode needs to an the image of the version of the OS installed as well.

Comment: I have the latest software for my iPhone. 6.1. That what you mean? @PascalBelloncle

Comment: but do you have 6.1 in XCode?

Comment: how do I know this? @PascalBelloncle

Comment: Organizer > LIBRARY > Software Images

Comment: where is the library in the organizer? @PascalBelloncle

Comment: Not sure that's the problem, though.  Under iPhone5 in organizer, do you see anything under Provisioning Profiles?

Comment: First of all, found the software images. there was nothing in there. and also i have an iPhone 4s. there is nothing under the provisioning profiles there because my developer certificate is under the library provisioning profiles @PascalBelloncle

Comment: And there is no button "Use for development" on the Iphone4S page in organizer?

Comment: there is none, I am almost positive I did select it earlier @PascalBelloncle

Comment: the button would look like it does here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/provision_device_for_development-generic.html.  You could also try adding your device to the provisioning portal, but this shouldn't be necessary.  Try also rebooting the phone.

Comment: I already have this set up in the portal. I think the issue comes down to this software image... It seems as though it stops loading my phone when i plug it in and it says "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" @PascalBelloncle

Comment: did you check that's the right UDID?  the one for the new phone?

Comment: what is a UDID exactly? @PascalBelloncle

Comment: call identifier in explorer, below ECID

Comment: AH! i figured it out! turns out i didn't have my new phone in the portal, so I added it to it and it solved everything! It all works now, Thank you for your help! ill accept your answer! an upvote would be greatly appreciated! @PascalBelloncle

Answer (score 3):

Have you added your device into the Developer Portal? Usually, this is done automatically thru Xcode. You have a new device, so it is obvious that the UDID has changed. Login to http://developer.apple.com, then iOS Provisioning Portal, and finally Devices.

Comment: Yes it is already set up in the portal. I am not sure if it is my old phone or the new one I got today @XCool

Comment: it *might* be set up in the portal via Xcode, but you really should look in [the official Apple iOS Provisioning Portal website](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) and make sure A) your device is listed in the list of devices and B) that your new device UDID is now included in all of the provisioning profiles for the apps you want to install. I bet the problem comes from B.

Comment: You were right. Turns out it wasn't my new iPhone set up in the portal but it was the last one. That was the issue! Thanks for the help! @MichaelDautermann